# Facebook FQL select 2 photos of every friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

How can I select 2 profile pictures of every friends?

I have this query:

```
SELECT object_id, src_small
FROM photo WHERE aid
IN ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner
IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM  friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND type="profile")
```

That displays every profile picture of every friends. Somehow I should limit to select only 2 per user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LIMIT statement at the end of a particular query as well as ORDER BY.

So you can get their 2 latest photos by adding

```
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 2
```

So to get 2 from EVERY friend, you'll have to run another subquery to fetch 2 from every friend:

```
SELECT object_id, src_small
    FROM photo WHERE pid
        IN ( SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid
        IN ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner
        IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM  friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND type="profile") ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 2)
```

Comment: If you add the "limit 2" you can only 2 rows from the query, not 2 from every friend

Comment: yeah your'e right, I'll fix up my answer to account for this. I havn't tested it though, so let me know if it works

Comment: FQL queries do not support ORDER BY or COUNT, and COUNT is what you need here if it was a classic SQL query. I'm in the same boat and have no solution yet.